# Why does Visual Studio 2010 keep crashing when I try to load a database?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datasource

I'm not sure what is going on. I create a new Windows Forms Application project in VB.NET without changing any of the settings or labels. Then I click on "Add Data Source" and go through the steps in my programming book. Except that Visual Studio is crashing with a message stating that VB encountered a problem...checking for causes...restarting VB.

Sometimes I get to click the "Debug and Run" button before this happens; other times, it occurs before I move all the labels in form from the data source; and still other times, it happens when I click the "Stop Debugging" button.

I have tried removing VB and reinstalling it, but this still is not helping. (If it matters, I'm getting my copy of VB from [www.dreamspark.com](http://www.dreamspark.com/)).

How can I stop Visual Studio from crashing whenever I try to load or work with a Data Source?

Comment: Sounds to me like a problem with the Data Source that you're adding. What type of database are you using? Can you give us some more details about how you've created this database? Do you have any way of testing that it's functioning properly from outside the VB/Visual Studio environment?

Answer (score 0):

Please write better formatted questions ok? icant barely comprehend what you are asking so ill give you the best i could guess from what im reading kkthx

Had same problem once... I needed to reinstall my VS AND SQL Server.

However, it could also be a problem with the database (versioning, bad file etc) or even if your MS SQL Server instance (I'm assuming you got one with your VS) isn't configured right.

Comment: the database i am using is an access file i downloaded from the cource curriculium out of my proggraming book. im not saying it is not corupt but there are other people in my class that are using it and dont seem to be having an issue. i have been having issues downloading SQL Server but even after i instaled it and i didn't say there was an issue with the install VB is still crashing. i will try to redownload all the files and programs an see if that makes a differecnce.